# How can I edit a css rule in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The purpose is that rows are dynamically added to a table and it is not as nice (and slower) to apply the rule manually later.

The specific example is that I am creating a tree table to represent a folder directory. Each folder is a `div`. In each `div`, there is a `ul` with an `li` for each columns' information. These `li` have a class name equivalent to the column name. This provides column width. I want to make the columns resizable however. I could do `$('.className').css('width', newWidth)` but then this wont apply to newly inserted items. Therefore, I want to modify the css rule. How do I do this?

Comment: You say `"rows are dynamically added to a table`", then "`Each folder is a div. In each div, there is a ul with an li`", is there any reason why you've not marked up tabular content with `table`?

Comment: my bet is: due to speed ;) table are very slow to be dom rendered, even with string manipulation.

Comment: @roselan Citation needed. I doubt they'd be prohibitively or even noticeably slow for what the OP's described.

Comment: How are you adding `newly inserted items`? If you use http://api.jquery.com/clone/ on an existing row, then the in-line CSS including the new width should be included.

Comment: The rows need to be dragable and hidable by folder. Hiding a div is really fast whereas hiding rows from a table isnt.

Comment: @StuperUser I am using backbone to load new items, but items can also be 'inserted' by having them be moved from other locations

Comment: `"by having them be moved from other locations"` what jQuery are you using for creating the mark-up when they're moved?

Comment: im using jquery ui's dragable/dropable to do the moving and simply moving the element as is.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery isn't really for editing CSS in that way.

It's possible to achieve what you want using `.css()` though. Don't change the width of individual elements, keep them 100% and resize their parent container, so any newly inserted items will be of width 100% and take the width of the parent container.

**EDIT**
How are you dynamically inserting/updating rows? If you use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) on an existing row, the in-line css added by `.css()` should be included, meaning you won't have to resize.

Comment: That wont work, as I explained above files (rows) are contained by their folder meaning that 100% width is the entire row.

Comment: Oh I see. Do other column `li`s need to be resized in this two? Could they have a static width and let the `li` for the information be the element that expands. If it's tabular why haven't you used a table?

Comment: Yea, I want the columns to be resizable. The reason Im using divs for table data is that the table is a tree-table, meaning that clicking on the 'open' link opens a folder and shows the sub-rows. In order to do this efficiently, I use divs.

Comment: The amount of functionality that want means that rolling your own might not be the best way forward, have a look at a plugin: http://www.jstree.com/ for example (since jQuery UI does not have a treeview yet)

Comment: jsTree is nice, but I need a table format to display file properties

Answer (score 2):

I've used this library for modifying css rules directly and it does the trick (it's a pure javascript solution though):

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript

how the library modifies rules directly:

```
document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[i].style.width=newWidth;
```

Comment: My firebug calls the getCSSRule operation insecure. Would you know why?

Comment: Are you modifying the css file from a different doman? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy if so that would explain why...

Comment: Nope, all local and same domain

Answer (score 2):

You could set up your html document with an empty style tag that has an ID.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style id="styleTarget"></style>
</head>
```

Then "append" rules into it using jQuery.

```
var columName = "whatever-your-column-name-is"
$('#styleTarget').append('.'+columName+' { width: '+newWidth+' }' );
```

Gets a little messy if you're updating the width a lot, but the CSS parser will go with the last rule in the list, so .append() works for updating previous width assignments.  You could use .html() instead of .append() to overwrite the contents of the stylesheet.

Comment: yea, this is what i thought about doing, i was just hoping that there was a better way

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cannot, unfortunately, directly manipulate CSS rules due to JavaScript native limitations; it's abilities extends to the DOM only which contains the elements of the page only, and as such not the CSS rules themselves (and even the CSS properties natively assigned to an element can be hard to obtain cross-browser).

Comment: Actually, you can manipulate CSS rules directly using document.styleSheets and styleSheet.cssRules - these are part of the DOM too (see my answer)